# Position an avatar next to a comment that wraps, using "display: flex"

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The question is similar to this one ([Positioning text next to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619841/positioning-text-next-to-an-image)), but regarding a case when we use "display: flex".

We have a comment that consists of an avatar image and a text next to it. A comment is supposed to appear on the right side of an avatar, and it does when the text is short, but otherwise it jumps under the avatar:

[image]

I want to set avatar's width and make a comment take the rest of the available width.

```css
a.inner-anchor {
  cursor: default;
}

div.github-comments {
  width: 70vw;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #e1e4e8;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 40px;
}

#gh-comments-list {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#gh-comments-list li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1.5em 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
}
#gh-comments-list li>a.user {
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 2.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3px;
}
#gh-comments-list a.user, #gh-comments-list a.comment-url {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
#gh-comments-list li>a.comment-url {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: .6em;
    opacity: .5;
}
#gh-comments-list li .comment-content {
    padding: 0 1.5em;
}
#gh-comments-list li>a.user img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #aaa;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="github-comments">
  <h2>Comments</h2>
  <ul id="gh-comments-list">

    <li>

      <a href="https://github.com/" class="user">
        <img class="avatar" src="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/45234211?v=4">
      </a>
      <div class="comment-content">
      <p>A Comment.</p>
      </div>

      <a href="https://github.com/" class="comment-url">#616068412 - 2020-04-19T07:44:35Z</a>

    </li>

    <li>

      <a href="https://github.com/" class="user">
        <img class="avatar" src="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/45234211?v=4">
      </a>
      <div class="comment-content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
      </div>

      <a href="https://github.com/" class="comment-url">#616068412 - 2020-04-19T07:44:35Z</a>

    </li>

    <li>

      <a href="https://github.com/" class="user">
        <img class="avatar" src="https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/45391682?v=4">
      </a>
      <div class="comment-content">
        <p>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
      </div>
      <a href="https://github.com/" class="comment-url">#618986438 - 2020-04-24T12:44:51Z</a>

    </li>

  </ul>


  <p id="no-comments-found">No comments found for this article.</p>
  <p id="loading-comments" style="display: none;">Loading comments...</p>
  <p id="next-comments-page" style="display: none;">next comments page</p>
  <p id="leave-a-comment">Join the discussion for this article on <a href="https://github.com/">this ticket</a>. Comments appear on this page instantly.</p>
</div>
```

Or here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/otmjrks6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, all you need to do is add `flex:1;` to the class you use for the comment text:

```
#gh-comments-list li .comment-content {
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    flex: 1;   /* This lets the element grow or shrink to fit */
}
```

This means that the element can grow or shrink to fit the space. Ref: [MDN Web Docs for flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

**Working Example:**

```css
a.inner-anchor {
  cursor: default;
}

div.github-comments {
  width: 70vw;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #e1e4e8;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 40px;
}

#gh-comments-list {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#gh-comments-list li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1.5em 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
}
#gh-comments-list li>a.user {
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 2.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3px;
    flex-basis: 2.5em;
}
#gh-comments-list a.user, #gh-comments-list a.comment-url {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
#gh-comments-list li>a.comment-url {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: .6em;
    opacity: .5;
}
#gh-comments-list li .comment-content {
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    flex:1;
}
#gh-comments-list li>a.user img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #aaa;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#no-comments-found {
  display: none;
}
#next-comments-page {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="github-comments">
  <h2>Comments</h2>
  <ul id="gh-comments-list">
  
    <li>

      <a href="https://github.com/" class="user">
        <img class="avatar" src="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/45234211?v=4">
      </a>
      <div class="comment-content">
      <p>A Comment.</p>
      </div>

      <a href="https://github.com/" class="comment-url">#616068412 - 2020-04-19T07:44:35Z</a>

    </li>

    <li>

      <a href="https://github.com/" class="user">
        <img class="avatar" src="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/45234211?v=4">
      </a>
      <div class="comment-content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
      </div>

      <a href="https://github.com/" class="comment-url">#616068412 - 2020-04-19T07:44:35Z</a>

    </li>

    <li>

      <a href="https://github.com/" class="user">
        <img class="avatar" src="https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/45391682?v=4">
      </a>
      <div class="comment-content">
        <p>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
      </div>
      <a href="https://github.com/" class="comment-url">#618986438 - 2020-04-24T12:44:51Z</a>

    </li>

  </ul>


  <p id="no-comments-found">No comments found for this article.</p>
  <p id="loading-comments" style="display: none;">Loading comments...</p>
  <p id="next-comments-page" style="display: none;">next comments page</p>
  <p id="leave-a-comment">Join the discussion for this article on <a href="https://github.com/">this ticket</a>. Comments appear on this page instantly.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
a.inner-anchor {
  cursor: default;
}

div.github-comments {
  width: 70vw;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #e1e4e8;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 40px;
}

#gh-comments-list {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#gh-comments-list li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1.5em 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
}
#gh-comments-list li>a.user {
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 2.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3px;
}
#gh-comments-list a.user, #gh-comments-list a.comment-url {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border-bottom: none !important;
}
#gh-comments-list li>a.comment-url {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: .6em;
    opacity: .5;
}
#gh-comments-list li .comment-content {
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    width: calc(100% - 94px);
}
#gh-comments-list li>a.user img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #aaa;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="github-comments">
  <h2>Comments</h2>
  <ul id="gh-comments-list">

    <li>

      <a href="https://github.com/" class="user">
        <img class="avatar" src="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/45234211?v=4">
      </a>
      <div class="comment-content">
      <p>A Comment.</p>
      </div>

      <a href="https://github.com/" class="comment-url">#616068412 - 2020-04-19T07:44:35Z</a>

    </li>

    <li>

      <a href="https://github.com/" class="user">
        <img class="avatar" src="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/45234211?v=4">
      </a>
      <div class="comment-content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. </p>
      </div>

      <a href="https://github.com/" class="comment-url">#616068412 - 2020-04-19T07:44:35Z</a>

    </li>

    <li>

      <a href="https://github.com/" class="user">
        <img class="avatar" src="https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/45391682?v=4">
      </a>
      <div class="comment-content">
        <p>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
      </div>
      <a href="https://github.com/" class="comment-url">#618986438 - 2020-04-24T12:44:51Z</a>

    </li>

  </ul>


  <p id="no-comments-found">No comments found for this article.</p>
  <p id="loading-comments" style="display: none;">Loading comments...</p>
  <p id="next-comments-page" style="display: none;">next comments page</p>
  <p id="leave-a-comment">Join the discussion for this article on <a href="https://github.com/">this ticket</a>. Comments appear on this page instantly.</p>
</div>
```

You need to give width in comment-content like "width: calc(100% - 94px)"